# Atlassian Stash: Is it possible to prevent merging pull requests containg merges?

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket-server

Some people in my team use `git pull` to sync their feature branches with master during development.

Due to that, pull requests end up having multiple merges, and as a result it's sometimes hard to reason about the code in the pull request and even harder when reviewing history in `gitk`.

[image: pull request with merge]

Preaching to them about advantages of using `git fetch && git rebase` or `git pull --rebase` doesn't help, so I'd like to set **a rule in Stash config panel to prevent anyone from merging pull requests that contain merge commits themselves**.

Is there some Stash plugin available that will make it possible?

I want to enforce the rule via automated check, so that I don't have to be "that guy" who always complains (if "MERGE" button is disabled, it's easier to enforce the convention).

Note that I am *not* the only one with merge privileges and I don't want to be the gatekeeper.

**Edit:**

It seems [this plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.carolynvs.reject-merge-commit-hook/server/installation) is what I was looking for. I will need to have a look at it.

Comment: Reject the pull request manually, and ask them to rebase (or do it yourself?).

Comment: @rubenvb rejecting non-conforming PRs would be only possible if I am the only one with merge privileges. I can not rebase for other people, I'd have to have write permission to other people's forks. It's easier to enforce conventions when they're checked via automated tools and "MERGE" button is disabled. Stash already has some built-in capabilities for that (disable "MERGE" button unless at least N people approved etc).

Comment: right, wrong (wrong), and right and impossible: You'll need to be the gatekeeper indeed, but you can (locally) rebase for other people just fine. Checking this might be possible with a git commit hook, but that ultimately depends on how Stash works. Note that disabling the merge "button" is not going to help because well, someone can always execute `git merge` locally and push the result.

Comment: Yeah that's true that I can fetch code, rebase myself, and push directly from my machine, but it's missing the point, I don't want to do the job of other people :) Regarding the second thing, luckily no one yet decided to skip pullrequest phase and push directly to upstream.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that [Stash plugin](https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/StashRebaseWorkflow) some time ago, I think to do pretty much what you describe.